# Unable to iterate through larger lists using zip

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I'm trying to test to see all the matching lists within 2 larger lists, and while my solution works for smaller data sets, the only match I've been able to find with larger data sets is [0,0]. Any clue what's causing this, or if there's a better way to check similar elements of 2 lists of lists?

Here's my code, with an example of 2 lists:

```
list1 = [ [0,0], [0,1], [0,2], ... , [900,800]] 
list2 = [ [0,0], [1,0], [1,1], ... , [900,800]]

#I want both [0,0] and [900,800] to be added to sharedPaths

sharedPaths = []

for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2):
  if l1 == l2:
    sharedPaths.append(l1)
```

Right now, sharedPaths only equals [[0,0]], but I want it to equal [[0,0],[900,800]]

Comment: Are `list1` and `list2` of the same size? (I'm guessing they aren't.) Regardless, you probably should be using a set here.

Comment: Does the position of the elements count? i.e. do you want to compare the elements in pairs only, as you do now?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `list` of `list` into `set` of `tuples` and use `intersection`

```
list1 = [ [0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [900,800]] 
list2 = [ [0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [900,800]]
list1 = set(tuple(l) for l in list1)
list2 = set(tuple(l) for l in list2)
list1.intersection(list2)
#{(0, 0), (900, 800)}
```

Comment: But that would match the elements regardless of their position.  Ask the OP if that's the case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're only interested in pairwise comparisons, you could use pandas like so:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series([[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [900,800]])
s2 = pd.Series([[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [900,800]])

sharedPaths = s1[s1 == s2]
```